# How does android.support break Javas type safety?

Tags: android, types, android-appcompat, preference

Today i encountered a very strange behavior. I know, I'm using deprecated APIs but nonetheless, this should not be possible from my understanding.

I have a `android.preference.PreferenceActivity`in which I put the following xml via `addPreferenceFromResource`:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:id="@+id/et_server_endpoint"
        android:key="server_endpoint"
        android:hint="http://192.168.100.42:8080"
        android:title="Server Endpoint"
        android:summary="Sets the Server Endpoint for the search"
        android:dialogTitle="Server Endpoint Settings"
        android:dialogMessage="Set the Servers endpoint"
        />
    <SeekBarPreference
        android:id="@+id/sb_phone_threshold"
        android:key="match_treshold"
        android:title="Matching Threshold"
        android:summary="Sets the minimum Score for matches"
        android:defaultValue="60"
        android:min="40"
        android:max="90"
        app:adjustable="true"
        app:showSeekBarValue="true"/>  
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Note that `SeekBarPreference` is an `android.support.v7.preference.Preference`

I have no problem inflating the xml. The Screen shows as expected. The problem comes when I want to get a reference to it:

`PreferenceActivity.findPreference(key)` is supposed to return an `android.preference.Preference` class (which the `SeekBarPreference` is not).

but this code returns a valid Pref:

```
 Preference match_treshold = findPreference("match_treshold");
```

I'm not allowed to cast it:

```
 if (match_treshold instanceof SeekBarPreference){}
```

because of

> error: incompatible types: Preference cannot be converted to SeekBarPreference

But surprisingly, if I debug the code I get this
[image: Debugging SeekBarPreference]

It states, that the class is `android.preference.SeekbarPreference`. If I google that, all I can find is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/SeekBarPreference

which states that it's based on `android.preference.SeekBarPreference`. But I cannot find this specific class.

Beside the - from my point of view - poor design decision, to not inherit support.v7 Preferences from the Android ones: What the hell is going on there?

EDIT: 
Due to request I post the Activity class

```
package com.my.company.domain.namespace;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.preference.SeekBarPreference;
import android.util.Log;

public class PrefActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.glass_prefs);
        Preference matchTreshold = findPreference("match_treshold");
//        code doesn't compile
//        if (match_treshold instanceof SeekBarPreference){}
        Log.d("Pref", "onCreate: SeekBarClass=" + matchTreshold.getClass().getName());
        //prints 'android.preference.SeekBarPreference'
        //one cannot import android.preference.SeekBarPreference
    }
}
```

you need to add

> implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'

to the build.gradle deps

Comment: Where does it state that it's a `android.preference.SeekbarPreference` and not an preference from the `v7` support library?
On a side-note: The preference library has always had a lot of quirks and at least earlier was very difficult to extend - using it out of the box it was easy enough, but if you wanted to do something more custom you'd end up with a lot of spaghetti code because of a very bad API design - not sure if it's gotten any better - I'd stay away from it if I were you - it's easier to write something on your own than use this imo.

Comment: It states that in the debugger on `match_threshold.getClass()`. Also there is no 
 `android.preference.SeekbarPreference` I could possibly use. I will probably write it myself, having always trouble doing something `custom` with Preferences

Comment: Please post your `PreferenceActivity` subclass, including all of its `import` statements.

Comment: The `SeekBarPreference` object you end up with is not an `android.support.v7.preference.Preference`. It is indeed an `android.preference.SeekBarPreference`. Your problem is that that class is hidden in the SDK [(source)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/preference/SeekBarPreference.java#30), but `PreferenceActivity` will still happily inflate it from your preference XML, because it does not check where that resource is coming from. There's nothing going on with the support classes here, aside from your import.

Comment: @MikeM. Oh happily inflating a hidden class is really great stuff! From my point the whole `preference` stack is broken af. Guess I will write a replacement over the holidays. If you're willing to post your last comment as answer I will accept.

Comment: Yeah, that's not great. I know what you mean. I usually don't use `Preference`s at all, if I can avoid it. I'm not sure they'd consider it a bug, since the documentation wouldn't reference the hidden platform `SeekBarPreference`, but you could file an issue, if you were so inclined. However, I'd imagine the likely response would be something along the lines of "you should be using the support classes anyway".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SeekBarPreference` object that you end up with in an `android.preference.PreferenceActivity` is indeed an `android.preference.SeekBarPreference`. The issue here is that that class is hidden in the SDK ([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/preference/SeekBarPreference.java)), so Android Studio will not suggest it for auto-completion, nor will it import it automatically. Since you're using the support libraries in your project, and the support version of `SeekBarPreference` is publicly available, that will be the class Android Studio tries to use there, thus the conflict.

Unfortunately, `PreferenceActivity` does not check from where the preference XML is coming, so it will happily create an instance of that platform class whenever it sees a `<SeekBarPreference>` tag. This is arguably a bug, but I'm not sure they'd consider it so, as that class is nowhere mentioned in the documentation.

You possibly could still use the platform `SeekBarPreference`, as it should work like any other basic `Preference`, though it might get a little hairy if you need to manipulate it directly. However, writing your own, as you've mentioned, is certainly a more solid, accessible solution. The platform class (linked above) is a rather simple `Preference` subclass, so you could even just copy that out into your project, almost as is. The relevant layouts ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/layout/preference_widget_seekbar.xml) and [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/layout/preference_widget_seekbar_material.xml)) are similarly straightforward, and don't rely on anything else hidden from the SDK.